# How can I trigger an LED with ultrasound

Tags: transistors, switches, ultrasound

#### CASE:

I would like to trigger a few independent LED's wireless-ly as cheap as physically possible. It is simply a LED connected to a battery. (The LED-part must be cheap, the transmitter does not matter)

The best idea I could come up with was broadcasting ultrasound at an unhearable/minimal-interference frequency, such as 200KHz for example, and then trigger the LED "on" when it detects anything on that frequency band, else off. See simple sketch below:[image: Simple Sketch]

It should turn on when the frequency is in a set range (180-220KHz). The transmission could be a simple sine wave.

I thought of using a really simple band-filter (like an FM radio design) but think that might be a bit expensive in parts? Could a simple coil work to trigger a transistor at a certain frequency or something?

*Apologies for the poorly asked question, I am a bit confused as to what options I have in the electronic domain to implement this concept.*

### EDIT

The range will vary from 1 to 300 meters. Line of sight is not guaranteed so IR (which is easiest) is not an option.

The frequency could be anything, even in the range of FM, so it would act like a little radio receiver triggering the LED on if there is activity on that channel.

People I talked to in person suggested using piezo-sensors as receivers for the signal and then a PIC chip to process the signal and decide whether to be on or off.

Comment: I'd like to answer the question a little better. Are you looking for one singular component or are you looking for some sub-circuit that you can drop into the On/Off trigger block? Also, are you looking for passive components only?

Comment: At what range do you want to trigger? IR is more conventional for remote control, but requires line-of-sight.

Comment: Shabab, Thanks for helping out. I am looking for a sub-circuit to drop into that block using some passive components. (Inductors/Capacitors etc.) - as "raw"/basic as possible.

Comment: range is vital as already said. It will help if you say what you are trying to achieve rather than guess a method.

Comment: Inductors are generally not the cheapest components, and neither are Ultra Sonic receivers. An IR receiver, as pjc50 suggested, with a small microcontroller, will likely be the cheapest option. ($2 in singles, down to $1 in volume). It will be difficult to buy just an US receiver (microphone) for that price.

Comment: @pjc50 - see the edit :)

Comment: Why dont you use the Piezo idea? It sounds really cool, You can also add some passive component network to cause an activation delay when at resonance, else the non resonance resistance being high enough to make it not work.